# Backing up - internal hard drive

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, backup, ssd, deja-dup

So I have read through tons of q's and a's here but haven't come across a suitable solution.

The issue here is that I want to backup my SSD with an internal hard drive using deja dup. I don't have/want to use a cloud service right now.

So the question is: when specifying the storage location, '/dev/sdb' is not a suitable path. Is there any way to backup the SSD using the internal drive?

I am aware of using:
`sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb`
but there are several advantages to using deja dup that I would like to utilize.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is sdb mounted? if so, to use the /dev/sdb specify the partition to backup to like sdb1, the sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb would be easier for a full hard drive full backup, but if you are just trying to protect your files why not just use the backup utility and change the path to the hard drive you want to backup to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to mount your internal drive, create a directory to which your user has write access, and use that. Depending on how you do it, your path should look like either `/mnt/drive_id/backup` or `/media/user/drive_id/backup`, assuming `backup` is the name you'll give to the backup directory.